# OpenGL ES - android - Square with two triangles - linear gradient?

Tags: android, opengl-es, alphablending

I have a square that is made ​​with two triangles.
The top-left should be red and the bottom right should be blue. Now i want a linear gradient from top-left to bottom-right.

I don't want a color on top-right and bottom-left. I've tried to give alpha 0, but this don't work. I see the black color.

```
        float vertices[] = 
    {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f
    }; 

    byte maxColor=(byte)255;

    byte colors[] = 
    {
        maxColor,       0,       0, maxColor,
        0,              0,       0,        0,
        0,              0,maxColor, maxColor,
        0,              0,       0,        0
    }; 

    byte indices[] = 
    {
        0, 3, 1,
        0, 2, 3
    };
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

EDIT:

I've now solved it differently. I fill the square with a gradient from top to bottom. Then I turn the square by 45 degrees and scale it up a bit.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Did you enable alpha blending? http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm

Comment: Do you really want those uncolored edges to blend out (be transparent), otherwise changing alpha doesn't make sense? Or do you just want them to get their color from the linear gradient automatically, without you needing to specify their color?

Comment: I want them to get their color from the linear gradient automatically, without needing to specify their color. And yes, alpha blending is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get a linear gradient over the quad, with the two other edges getting their color automatically from the interpolation, then don't mess with alpha, it's (usually) only used for transparency effects.

Unfortunately you cannot just specify a color for some vertices and get an automatic interpolation for the others. The rasterizer doesn't just magically use linear gradient, using information from other primitives. It just interpolates the color of a primitive's (single triangle's) vertices across the primitive. So you need to give your other vertices some color.

But in your case that's rather easy. Your vertices are actually both half-way along the "gradient", thus you can just do the interpolation yourself and give them the correct colors, in your case `(128, 0, 128)` (+-1, but who cares):

```
byte colors[] = 
{
    255,   0,   0, 255, 
    128,   0,   0, 255, 
      0,   0, 255, 255, 
    128,   0, 128, 255
};
```

The fact that the rasterizer interpolates across the individual triangles independently may introduce some interpolation artifacts deviating from a pure gradient (though, in your case probably not). In this case it may make a difference if the quad's diagonal (the border between the two triangles) goes along the gradient or through the gradient.

Comment: This looks good. byte colors[] = 
{
    255,   0,   0, 255, 
    128,   0, 128, 255, 
      0,   0, 255, 255, 
    128,   0, 128, 255
};
But, what is, when i use random colors. Is that so, that i must take the half. +-1?

Comment: @user1405328 Well, you have linear gradient and your corners ar halfway along the gradient, so their values are the 50-50 interpolation of the two end point colors. Of course this changes with respect to the position of your corner vertices projected onto  gradient line.